# TCPDF: Vertical alignment in a TD with text and image

Tags: php, image, vertical-alignment, tcpdf

I have been looking through various forums but have not found a way to solve my problem.

I have a piece of HTML which I display in the view and render to PDF with TCPDF. The HTML looks fine but it does not seem to work in TCPDF.

I have the following table cell that contains text (3a-2b) and next to it the image. The alignment should be like in the second image.

PDF:[image: table cell pdf] Browser:[image: table cell html]

- I have tried CSS (vertical-align, height, line-height, margin, padding ...)
- I have found this Article http://bytethinker.com/blog/tcpdf-and-vertical-alignment-of-table-cells

but nothing seems to work.

I know I could use the entire text as an image but this is just an example.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the text and the image in a separate `<td>` and applying a `line-height` of 6px to the `<td>` containing the text did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Adding style="line-height:50%;" in image tag works for me. Please give this a try. In my case, I wanted to vertical align image in table cell. You can add div in table cell and can add image or text inside it. Below works for me.

`<div align="center"><img src="images/logo_example.png" border="0" height="30" width="30" style="line-height:50%;"/></div>`

Answer (score -1):

TCPDF supports HTML and CSS very poorly, but there are some undocumented HTML and CSS attributes. Searching the sourcecode I found an "aling" attribute for the img tag supporting "middle". So this could do what you want: 
`<img src="..." align="middle">`